# Inherited Abstract Classes in python

Tags: python, inheritance, abc

In python, can I define an interface (abstract class) by inheritance from another abstract class?
If I try:

```
import abc
ABC = abc.ABCMeta('ABC', (object,), {})

class interface(ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def method(self, message):
        return


class InterfaceExtended(ABC, interface):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def NewMethod(self, message):
        return
```

I get an error on the  "InterfaceExtended" class :

```
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases ABC, Interface
```

Comment: Note: If you're on Python 3.4+ then you could use `ABC` class from `abc` module itself instead of re-defining it.

Comment: no, I forgot to state that I'm in python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't inherit from ABC in your second class. The interface it derives from already inherits ABC